# When is $.cache deemed too large?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, browser-cache

I recently read in [this tutorial](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks) that certain `jQuery` leaks are trackable through the `$.cache` variable, and you should always check its size, if it's too large, you're doing something wrong.

Well, how large is too large? Is there a way to inspect a variable to see how much memory it is eating up?

I'm working on a website that caches 210 objects only by loading the homepage. Is that too much? I would appreciate a thorough explanation about the issue here.

Comment: It's not about how large it is, but how it grows over time. If the cache is not bounded (i.e. increases forever) you've probably got a memory leak.

Comment: jQuery is truly browser compatible. It brings the IE problem of properly disposing of elements to all browsers.

Comment: You would be hard pushed to strain modern memory capabilities if you are sensible. Unless of course you create a large enough memory leak. There is no magic amount of memory, it all depends on a user's hardware. Do you care about people using computers from the 90s?

Comment: @ChuckE: It's not terribly practical to manually test `jQuery.cache` for size. What it ultimately comes down to is that if you're going to use jQuery, and you don't want leaks, then you ***must*** use jQuery to destroy elements. If you use any other API, you'll create leaks. jQuery's system is very fragile in this way. It's really pretty unfortunate.

Comment: @George Reith, no, but I care about optimization and optimal use of the resources of the end device. It already sucks in the garbage collected languages not to have a way to free the memory on-the-fly, one has to at least learn how to use the garbage collector properly, regardless of quality of the device it is addressed to (which can be any).

Comment: @user1689607: that is a useful tip indeed. Does it work as well if I "clean" an element's inner html with the .html method from jquery while having one of its intern elements instantiated somewhere else, like let's see, an handler? I'm just talking about hipothetical cases. Which functions I should be using then to remove the elements?

Comment: @ChuckE: jQuery AFAIK does a thorough job of cleaning elements as long as you use their methods. So if you use jQuery's `.html("")` to clear out some container, jQuery will search through every element in the container, and clean up any data that jQuery stored in `jQuery.cache` for those elements. If you use `.innerHTML = ""`, then jQuery's data is orphaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.cache`'s size at face value does not tell anything about memory leaks. It could be very small and still have a memory leak, or it could be very large and not have any memory leak.

If you know you have 10 event listeners bound with jQuery on the page at a time, and yet `$.cache` has entries for more, then you know you are leaking.

A huge memory saver is to use event delegation rather than attaching event listeners to each individual element.

Say:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

`$("li").on( "click", fn )` would attach 3 individual event handlers (more, if you have more li's of course), whereas `$("ul").on( "click", "li", fn)` would attach just one regardless of how many li-elements you have and yet have the same result.

---

Example of leak:

```
$("button").click( function() {
    $("#target")[0].innerHTML = "";
    $("<div>").appendTo( $("#target")).click( $.noop );
    $("#log").text( Object.keys( $.cache ).length );
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SGZW4/1/

Reason being that .innerHTML is used, which is not part of jQuery so it cannot do clean up.

Fix is to use jQuery method for the same:

```
$("button").click( function() {
    $("#target").html("");
    $("<div>").appendTo( $("#target")).click( $.noop );
    $("#log").text( Object.keys( $.cache ).length );
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SGZW4/2/

Comment: that's a good tip. but how can I use the $.cache variable to better inspect my memory usage? One example I just thinked of: Check the number of elements cached,  click on a button and have an expected visual behaviour, check the number of elements cached again, click on the button which "resets" the previous action, and see if the cached elements number is the same as in the beginning of this test. Is this, for instance, a  good use of the $.cache to test memory usage?

Comment: @ChuckE I wouldn't worry about $.cache, one way to avoid the whole thing is to exclusively use event delegation to static elements that are never removed in the first place. Otherwise just make sure you are always using jQuery methods, and not the standard DOM ones: http://jsfiddle.net/SGZW4/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/SGZW4/2/

Comment: humm, interesting. So that means, for the tested case, $.cache can't even check there was a memory leak?

Comment: ups, nevermind that, bad interpretation from me. That is exactly the right way to achieve some kind of memory leak inspection with $.cache. Thanks.

Comment: could you please insert your leak and noleak examples in your response body? I think they are key to the problem I was trying to describe with the question. Then I'll gladly approve it ;)